# How to depending on the user input create a certain amount on functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to create a program in Python in which I ask the user how many toys the user has. And then for each toy ask the user the name of the toy and its price.what piece of code do I use to ask a certain amount of times the question and each time have the answer stored in a different variable?? Sorry if it's a stupid question but I really need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `for` loop, and store the toys in a list or a dictionary, not separate variables.

```
 toys = []  # or toys = {}
 for i in range(number_of_toys):
     # get name
     # get price
     toys.append(Toy(name, price))
     # or toys[name] = Toy(name, price)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would store the toys in some kind of data structure, for example a list:

```
my_toys = []
how_many = int(input("How many toys do you have? "))
for i in range(how_many):
    toy = input("What's your toy number {}? ".format(i+1))
    my_toys.append(toy)
print("All my toys:", my_toys)
```